# Place labels between boxes on boxplot

Tags: r

The way I want to represent my data is "Foo in X vs Foo in Y: pval=bar".

Is there any way I can put that label between two ticks under boxes in a boxplot, instead of below one of the boxes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly: Do you 1) want to move the automatically created labels of the tickmarks of the x-axis or do you 2) want to add some kind of additional label? If 1) maybe have a look at the `at` argument of `boxplot()`; if 2) `mtext()` could be what you're looking for. Otherwise, reproducible example code with a limited data set would help a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: @Where'smytowel I was referring to your 1), which apparently is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649184/boxplot-one-x-axis-tick-mark-label-for-two-boxes .

Comment: Well, it's only a duplicate if you're using ggplot …

Comment: @Where'smytowel I don't always use ggplot2, but if someone had asked me "Can you use ggplot2? 'Cause I know a function there that can do this", I would have replied "Sure!"